# how do you do : "sudo chown USER /dev/ttyUSB0" on Windows?

Tags: windows, port, admin, sudo, chown

How do you do : "sudo chown USER /dev/ttyUSB0" on Windows ?

This command is necessary for me to be able to upload code from a PC to an Arduino board, however I have no idea on how to perform the same operation under Windows.

Thanks !

Comment: It's unlikely that there will be an exact Windows equivalent for this, as it is structured completely differently. Just look for instructions how to do what you want to do on Windows

Answer (score 1):

There’s no ttyUSB0 devices in Windows.

In *nix, ttyUSB# devices are usually USB to serial adapters. In Windows, they’re just a regular COM ports like COM1 or COM3.

Normally, you already have the permission to read/write those COM ports, even as a non-admin. No need to change those security settings.
If you don’t have the access, I suggest posting another question about that.